# How to replace word in string if it contains a word

Tags: string, replace, python-re

I have a string *SELECT * FROM context_information WHERE language = 'Croatian'*. This is an output from a function, where *context_information* is sometimes simply *context* or something else that contains the word context.

I want to replace the word that contains the *context* to simply context.